# Why is find function not recognized?

Tags: javascript

```
let students = ({id: 1, name: 'Alice'}, {id:2, name: 'Bob'}, {id: 3, name: 'Charlie' });
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    //res.send('Home Page');
    //console.log(__dirname);
    //console.log(req.url);
    //console.log(req.query);
    res.sendFile('./views/index.html', {root: __dirname});
});


//send students with a particular ID back to the client
app.get('/students/:sid', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.params);

    let id = req.params.sid;

    let student = students.find(element => element.id === parseInt(id));

    console.log(student);

    res.json(student);

});
```

in the console it says that the find function is not a function and is throwing me an error and I do not understand why.

Comment: `students` is not array, array is [...]

Answer (score 2):

An array is initialized with square brackets, the first line should look like this:

```
let students = [{id: 1, name: 'Alice'}, ...];
```

Comment: Wow went right over my head thanks so much

Comment: @Nikoo mark the answer as answered if it solves your issue

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar The term is "accepted", and users have to wait a certain amount of time before they can accept an answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @HereticMonkey okay